# HTML5 attribute for ZK

Tags: html, zk

I have some html5 written which i need to re-implement for a ZK6 application.

I am struggling with the data-* attribute.

For example

```
 <div class="caption lft"
                                 data-x="140"
                                 data-y="60"
                                 data-speed="900"
                                 data-start="800"
                                 data-easing="Sine.easeOut"> <h:img id="tp-mainImgSlide-02" src="img/slider/pic1.png" alt=""/> 
                                 </div>
```

I get the error

```
Cause: Method setData-x not found for class org.zkoss.zul.Div
```

Has anyone encountered this issue with HTML5 in ZK 6 and do you know how to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use a `h:div` with `h` being the namespace for html, the same way you did for `img`:

```
 <h:div class="caption lft" data-x="140" data-y="60" data-speed="900" data-start="800" data-easing="Sine.easeOut"> 
     <h:img id="tp-mainImgSlide-02" src="img/slider/pic1.png" alt=""/> 
 </div>
```

the html `div` is not the same as the zul one.

Comment: I am getting error : Failed to assign [data-x=140] to <Div dBbE32>

Answer (score 4):

You have two options for specifying HTML5 `data` attributes in ZUL file

First option, use native html element as suggested by RC.

Second option, use [client attribute](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZUML_Reference/ZUML/Namespaces/Client_Attribute) namespace. This should work with any ZK component.

```
<zk xmlns:ca="xmlns:ca="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zk/client/attribute">
  <div ca:data-x="140"></div>
</zk>
```

This will output a native div html element with `data-x` attribute